# Octopus Deploy to Azure Web App - Doesn't unpack

Tags: azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

I'm new to Octopus so followed https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/cicd/200.3x-CICD-CDwithOctopus.html

Right at the end, Octopus has told me it's "successfully" deployed to my Azure Web App. However, when I browse to it I get:

`You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

Browsing the Kudu console of the site I can see the following files have been created in `D:\home\site\wwwroot`:

- OctopusWalkthroiugh.deploy-readme.txt
- OctopusWalkthroiugh.deploy.cmd
- OctopusWalkthroiugh.SetParameters.xml
- OctopusWalkthroiugh.SourceManifest.xml
- OctopusWalkthroiugh.zip

So something has been deployed, but it's like a final "unpackage" step hasn't happened. I don't know the terminology so my searching hasn't been very helpful.

What have I missed?

Comment: I also can reproduce the issue that you mentioned. Do you have a try to use octopus MS deploy? I recommand that you could ask help from https://help.octopus.com/

Comment: It appears that the application is being packaged twice, in 5.6 and again in 5.11, so you end up deploying the first package (OctopusWalkthrough.zip) to the web host rather than the app itself.